# How can I trigger a jQuery script from content loaded using the load() function

Tags: jquery

I am loading different content into a table cell from a list of options using jQuery AJAX which works fine.  However the loaded content includes a button (class=addButton) that should also trigger loading of content when clicked but it do not.  Is it possible to get loaded content to trigger scripts included in the main page at all, if not is there any other way of embedding the script in the loaded content.

```
// Scripts embedded in the main page
$("#menu1").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("Menu1Content.html");
    })
$(".addButton").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("AddFormForMenu1Content.html");
    })
```

//Main page content

```
<table >
 <tr>
  <td id='#menu1'>Menu 1</td>
  <td id='#div1'>Content goes here</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

//Menu1Content.html

```
<button class='addButton'>ADD</button>
```

//AddFormForMenu1Content.html

```
<button id='menu1'>SUBMIT</button>
```

The basic flow is as follows:

1. Select menu option - display content in panel
2. Perform action in panel
3. Display original content

Note that the actual content is dynamically loaded from a database using php.  The above example is just using static html to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click`. That way, you can bind the click event to the document and make it respond to clicks on any element that matches a selected, regardless of when they were added:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu1", function(){
    $("#div1").load("Menu1Content.html");
});
$(document).on("click", ".addButton", function(){
    $("#div1").load("addDeviceForm.php");
});
```

Comment: That was quick, I'll give it a go

Comment: Did you get an error in the console? I had a surplus of parentheses, which should now have been fixed. Can you try again?